# SSIS converting Time Stamp format using derived column

Tags: ssis

I have a timestamp in a text file that looks like this: `7/2/2013 17:40:22`

I need to convert it to this: `2013-07-02 17:40:22.913`

Using a derived column, I tried this: `(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)TIME_STAMP`
and

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP,1,4) + "-" + 
SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP,5,2) + "-" + 
SUBSTRING(TIME_STAMP,7,2))
```

But I am getting an error: Conversion between types DT_STR and DT_DBTIMESTAMP is not supported.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you must go the route of casts, let me know and I'll edit this answer to reflect it. Otherwise, simplify your life and fix your Flat File Connection Manager. By default, it's going to assume every column coming in is varchar(50). This gets tricky with dates and times because well known formats that *should* just convert require far too much expression garbage to make them work.

In your case, change the type to `DT_DATE` I know you'd think it's for dealing date only but that'd be `DT_DBDATE`.

[image]

By simply changing to that data type, I was able to import your value without issue.

[image]

Comment: Hellow Downvoter, can you help me understand what you find distasteful in my answer so that I may improve upon it?

Answer (score -1):

using token will do ... assume your timestamp is in a string(WSTR) format

```
TOKEN([Order Date],"/",3) + "-" + TOKEN([Order Date],"/",1) + "-" + TOKEN([Order Date],"/",2)
```