# Why SSIS Date Conversion Failure regardles of validation methods

Tags: ssis

I have a column in a text-file with dates like this: `20131207`.
I and trying to convert the date like this but everything I have tried has failed.

**Here is my code:** I have modified it many times to fix this problem.

```
(LEN(TRIM(MyDate)) < 8) || (TRIM(MyDate) == " ") || 
(ISNULL(MyDate)) ? NULL(DT_DBDATE) : 
(DT_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING(TRIM(MyDate),1,4) + "-" + 
SUBSTRING(TRIM(MyDate),5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(TRIM(MyDate),7,2))
```

Where am I going wrong?

I checked Retain Null Values in the *Flat Source Task*.

Update: Here is the error message:

```
The conditional operation failed.
The "Rename Columns (My_Table)" failed because error code 0xC0049063 occurred, 
and the error row disposition on "Rename Columns (My_Table).Outputs[Derived 
Column Output].Columns[MyDate]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred 
on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error 
messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

I need to convert the data in the text file to date, from `20131207` to `2013-12-07` but I want to insert null if the data in the text file is less then 8 in length or cannot be converted to date.

Comment: why dont try with sql `convert(date,@a)` put in a sql execute task ?

Comment: Is there a reason [this answer doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20388530/ssis-converting-time-stamp-format-using-derived-column)

Comment: @billinkc: i guess [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20388530/ssis-converting-time-stamp-format-using-derived-column) and the present question are quite different ??

Comment: @Unavg guy: you mean transform `20131207` into this `2013-12-07` ??

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to accomplish. I am getting the data from a text file. And the data is the file is format like this: `20131207` which I want to convert to this: `2013-12-07'

Comment: @UnaverageGuy : can you try the answer i posted !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

add a new flat file source then add a derived column then in expression do this

```
 `LEFT(date,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(date,5,2) + "-" + RIGHT(date,2)`
```

the package :

[image]

with output like this :

[image]

Comment: Thank you my friend. I added your solution to mine like this:
 
`(LEN(TRIM(MyDate)) < 8) || (TRIM(MyDate) == "") || (ISNULL(MyDate)) ? NULL(DT_DBDATE) : (DT_DBDATE)(LEFT(MyDate,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(MyDate,5,2) + "-" + RIGHT(MyDate,2))`

This works and no errors, thanks again for your patience. You made this happen!

Answer (score 0):

Trim(MyDate)==" " should be Trim(MyDate)==""

Comment: Hello: I tired all of that, the code above derived from many variations as I stated, trying to find the problem. The objective is to process the data outside the DB, I do not want to make corrections in the DB once the data is entered. Get the data from text-file, clean and insert.